# Unable to display controls in Android project activity using openCV

Tags: java, android, templates, opencv, matching

My intention is to run template matching on Android device using openCV. I have set up new Android project to work with openCV. I've also added code snippet to my Start.java file to initialize openCV libs. After this point I am unable to display any controls on my activity.  Code is really simple (blank), executes with no errors, but I'm not even able to see the automatic "Hello World" string on my mobile, and I'm unable to edit the activity in any way. Any ides why?

Start.java code is:

```
package com.example.match;

import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Start extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error


    }}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
01-04 00:57:25.385: I/ActivityManager(2690): Start proc com.example.match for activity com.example.match/.Start: pid=28971 uid=10105 gids={}
01-04 00:57:25.395: D/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(4911): OnReceive Start
01-04 00:57:25.395: D/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(4911): PauseSlideShow Start
01-04 00:57:25.395: D/CalendarAppWidgetProviderAgenda(5097): ACTION_HOME_PAUSE: false
01-04 00:57:25.420: I/OrientationDebug(2690): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
01-04 00:57:25.420: I/OrientationDebug(2690): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return true #4
01-04 00:57:25.455: I/Launcher(2851): onWindowFocusChanged(false)
01-04 00:57:25.460: D/dalvikvm(28971): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 53% free 2529K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 20ms
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(28971): Trying to get library list
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/dalvikvm(28971): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.match/lib/libopencv_info.so 0x405130e0
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/dalvikvm(28971): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.match/lib/libopencv_info.so 0x405130e0
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/dalvikvm(28971): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.match/lib/libopencv_info.so 0x405130e0, skipping init
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(28971): Library list: ""
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(28971): First attempt to load libs
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(28971): Trying to init OpenCV libs
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(28971): Trying to load library opencv_java
01-04 00:57:25.470: D/dalvikvm(28971): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.match/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x405130e0
01-04 00:57:35.339: W/ActivityManager(2690): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
01-04 00:57:35.420: W/ActivityManager(2690): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{405415f8 com.example.match/.Start}
01-04 00:57:37.999: W/PowerManagerService(2690): Timer 0x3->0x1|0x0
```